# Distinguish between RTCPeerConnection's

Tags: javascript, html, stream, webrtc, webcam

In my web application, I display four streams coming from the WebRTC `RTCPeerConnection` simultaneously. Each time I receive an offer, I check if the video element is busy, if I do not show the stream.

```
bobConn.onaddstream = AddingStream;

function AddingStream(evt) {

    if (video1.readyState === 0){
        video1 = video1 = attachMediaStream(video1, evt.stream);
        video1attached = true;
    } else if (video1.readyState === 4 && video2.readyState === 0){
        video2 = attachMediaStream(video2, evt.stream);
        video2attached = true;
    } else if (video2.readyState === 4 && video3.readyState === 0){
        video3 = attachMediaStream(video3, evt.stream);
        video3attached = true;
    } else if (video3.readyState === 4 && video4.readyState === 0){
        video4 = attachMediaStream(video4, evt.stream);
        video4attached = true;
    }
};
```

Now I am trying to handle an event in which the disconnection of any of the connections will occur (for example, the device that streams will be turned off), in which case the `video` element will be replaced with an image informing about the disconnection.

To know which video to replace I need to know which connection was interrupted.

Can anyone tell me how to distinguish between `RTCPeerConnection` connections?

edit:

```
function getBrowserRTCConnectionObj () {
    var servers = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'}, {'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};

    if (window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {
        return new mozRTCPeerConnection(servers);
    } else if (window.webkitRTCPeerConnection) {
            return new webkitRTCPeerConnection(servers);
    } else if (window.msRTCPeerConnection) {
            return new msRTCPeerConnection(servers);
    } else {
        return new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    }
};

function getStream(){
    //pytanie: nowy objekt zawsze przyjmuje nazwe connection
    bobConn = getBrowserRTCConnectionObj();
    bobConn.onicecandidate = sentIceCandidates;
    bobConn.onaddstream = AddingStream;
    bobConn.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(TempDescriptions),
        function() {
            bobConn.createAnswer(gotDescription, displayError);
            //toggleVideo();
    }, displayError);   
};
```

ShowStreams():

```
function showStreams(){
    var streams = connection.getRemoteStreams();
    for (var stream of streams) {
        console.log("Remote streams: " + stream.id);
    };
};
```

Comment: There's only one `RTCPeerConnection` here from what I can tell. Are you asking how to distinguish between different streams? If so, the answer will depend on exactly how you "disconnect" or "interrupt" them, and what you mean by that. The WebRTC API has changed over the last few years away from streams to instead dealing with the video and audio tracks contained in a stream directly, mostly to solve ambiguity around questions like these. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @jib, not completely, I wrote a function that implements the RTCPeerConnection connection (I edited the post), the point is that each time the value bobConn is overwritten with the new RTCPeerConnection object. I have no idea how to assign an object to a new variable and I do not want to create an object outside the getStream () function.

Comment: @jlb, each time it calls the getStream() function and the connection succeeds, it gets another stream.id from the getStreams () function and always gets only one value.